# some of the open graph image not showing on linkedin

Tags: linkedin-api, facebook-opengraph

I am using a wordpress blog,some of the open graph image not showing on linkedin. but it showing if i change the post category.every post works fine with facebook and twitter. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

maybe these images are too small.

I had the same problem with an logo. Facebook-developer-tools told me (Error was shown only on Chrome):

**Provided og:image URL, 'IMAGE' was not valid because it did not meet the minimum size constraint of 200px by 200px.**

BTW.: Take a look at these [Article on Point 4](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices)